# Calculate the derivative and find its domain: $\;f(x)= \sqrt{\ln(x)+2}$

Tags: derivatives

I calculated the derivative as $$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2x \sqrt{2+\ln x}}$$

How do I find out the domain?

Answer (score 4):

To make sure that the denominator $\not = 0$, we need to require

$$\{x:\ln x+2\gt 0\}=(e^{-2},\infty)$$

Comment: I would require  $x>0 \cap \{\ln x + 2 >0\}$ (initially excluding $x=0$), instead. The result does not change, though.

Comment: $x\not = 0 \cap \{\ln x + 2 >0\}$ is better. Thanks!

Comment: ...and $x>0$ due to the presence of $\ln x$. Your result is correct (+1)

Answer (score 1):

The domain is the set $\{x:\ln x+2\ge 0\}=[e^{-2},\infty)$

Comment: Why? can you show your steps

Comment: At $x = e^{-2}$, the derivative is not defined, in case the OP was looking for the domain of $f'(x)$.

Comment: @user3924310 I am assuming that you want the domain of the function and I have also assumed that the function is real valued. Otherwise, the domain is the whole $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: If the OP is asking for the domain of the derivative then the domain is $(e^{-2},\infty)$. Basically by domain we mean the  set of values of $x$ (in $\mathbb{R}?$) for which the function does not "blow up" to $\pm \infty$.